# Passing date parameter to BIRT report as string not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to BIRT. I have developed a report where I am passing three parameters via url. the first is integer and other two is date passed as string. I am opening the report from my php application. I installed my report viewer in apache tomcat server. The url that is created is like this;

http://localhost:8080/birt/frameset?__report=D%3A%5Cxampp%5Ctomcat%5Cwebapps%5Cbirt%5Creport%5Cdiganta%5CproductionSummeryEmpWise.rptdesign&RP_employee_id=699&RP_fromDate=2015-12-01&RP_toDate=2016-01-01

If I query in report testing the query works fine. But passing as parameter is not working.
I have attached my  report.
Can any one tell me where I am doing wrong.

My MySQL query is like this;

```
SELECT  p.supervisor_id,p.employee_id,p.operation_id,po.description,po.rate,SUM(p.quantity) 
AS quantity,e.employee_pre_code,e.employee_code,e.supervisorwise_serial,e.employee_name,
e.designation_id,d.designation_name

FROM production p 

LEFT JOIN production_operation po ON p.operation_id = po.operation_id
LEFT JOIN employee e ON p.employee_id = e.employee_id  
LEFT JOIN designation d ON e.designation_id = d.designation_id

WHERE p.employee_id = ? 

AND p.production_date >= ?     --"2015-10-01" 
AND p.production_date <= ?    --"2016-01-02"  

GROUP BY p.operation_id

ORDER BY po.description DESC
```